# 3 subplots (2 graphs & 1 colorbar)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I want to plot a figure that is made up of 3 subplots: 2 of them are normal graphs and 1 has a color bar.

Here are the images:
[image]
[image]

So basically I want to put the images next to each other (horizontally).

Here is the code I wrote to generate the `first figure`:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 40, c=z)
plt.colorbar()
```

and here's the code for the `second figure`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey = True)

axes[0].plot(z, y, 'ok')
axes[1].plot(x, y, 'ok')
```

In order to place the figures horizontally next to each other I tried to do the following: (but I got an error)

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey = True)
axes[0].plot(z, y, 'ok')
axes[1].plot(x, y, 'ok')
axes[2].scatter(x, y, s = 40, c = z)
fig.colorbar()
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting an error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar you have to pass neccessary argument `mappable` to `colorbar` method of `Figure`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,1,3]
z = [10, 20, 30, 40]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey = True)
axes[0].plot(z, y, 'ok')
axes[1].plot(x, y, 'ok')
a2 = axes[2].scatter(x, y, s = 40, c=z)
fig.colorbar(a2)

plt.show()
```

Code above works fine.

As for the first example, `plt` is just a wise shortcut to latest `Figure` instance. As far as you created only 1 plot and 1 artist, everything works good.